# How to call a method in python selenium from separate file

Tags: python, selenium

I try to call a method in python from separate file: (sample below)

```
#File1.py

from selenium import webdriver
class Myclass1():

 try:
  ------
 except Exception as e:
  print(e)
  ------

 def ab(self):
    --------

 def cd(self):
    --------
```

then I need to call ab and cd method to file#2

```
#File2.py

from file1 import Myclass1

def test1()
 callfromfile1 = Myclass1()
 callfromfile1.ab()
 callfromfile1.cd()

if __name__== "__test__":
main()
```

Prob:
when I try to run the file2.py
it only runs the try and except but it doesn't run the methods ab and cd.
thanks

Comment: Are you missing parens?  `callfromfile1.ab` -> `callfromfile1.ab()`

Comment: Forgot to add it, thanks. done doing edit.. but still it doesn't run the callfromfile1.ab() and cd().

Comment: where are the `:` while defining the function and classes?

Comment: in #file1 `class Myclass1():` . thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write proper python code as follow:-

File1.py

```
class Myclass1():
    try:
        print 'try and catch function()'
    except:
        print 'exception'

    def ab(self):
        print 'ab()'

    def cd(self):
        print 'cd()'
```

File2.py

```
from File1 import Myclass1

def test1():
    callfromfile1 = Myclass1()
    callfromfile1.ab()
    callfromfile1.cd()

if __name__== "__main__":
    test1()
```

Output:-

```
try and catch function()
ab()
cd()
```

Comment: Done, I already did this coding. I also tried to have a try and catch to each methods to know the error on each steps but when i run the `file2.py` it doesn't return any error. it only run the `file1.py` try and except but not the methods `ab` and `cd`.